# How do I increase font size in L4D2 in-game chat?

Tags: linux, left-4-dead-2

On my Linux machine it’s too small and I have to move my head to be able to read anything written there.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure about the actual text size, but maybe lowering the screen resolution will enlarge text. This does come with a sacrifice of quality, though.

Answer (score 3):

Right out of the box, you cannot change the font of the chat. However, I did some searches on potential solutions, and I found this:

http://www.l4dmaps.com/details.php?file=15715 - Seems like you can make those adjustments and get the font from L4D1, which also means you might be able to configure it further.

Comment: Can you summarize the important bits on the far side of that link, so that if the link ever goes dead, this answer will still be userful?

Comment: it is a mod which uses the l4d typeface for l4d2, and requires a minor autoexec.cfg edit to finalize the install (to match resolution). If the link goes dead, then the solution does too.

Answer (score 1):

Garuda Linux KDE Gaming Edition is perfect for Left For Dead 2. Set the global scaling to 200% which you will able to read them easily.